# Bootstrap nav bar list is stacked rather than alongside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to execute a basic Bootstrap nav bar example:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Look at what's happening in the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ThePomodoro/pen/xgMxzp) (which has Bootstrap installed). Why are the items in the navbar stacking atop each other, and not sitting alongside each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Bootstrap 4 (in the Codepen) and the navbar has changed. If you want a simple horizontal (non collapsing) you need to include `navbar-toggleable-xl` since the navbar is stacked vertically by default..

**Update for 4.0.0** `navbar-toggleable-*` has changed to **`navbar-expand-*`**

For original question:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-toggleable-xl bg-faded">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/TVDW57B4SL

[Read more in the docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, but the version of Bootstrap that you need is version 3.3.7. It looks like you are trying to call a newer version of Bootstrap in your Codepen.

Here is your same code using the older Bootstrap:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjPazv

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```